# Sharpening a curve

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis

[image]

I have a frequency domain graph as shown. I need to "sharpen" the curve to get a better response, and computing large butterworth orders is not possible on my machine. Hence, I would like to know if there is a math technique to sort of sharpen the curve below.

Comment: It would help if you could at least tell us what the blue, green, and red lines represent mathematically.  Presumably, these are transfer functions of some kind, and you've combined the filters to get the product of the transfer functions (in red). What filters are you using here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have two transfer functions here.  Call the blue $H_1(f)$ and the green $H_2(f)$.  Presumably, the red is the product $H_1(f)H_2(f)$.

It seems that the important behavior is that near $f = 1000\,Hz$. We can "sharpen" it, perhaps, in the following way:

Instead of $H_1(f)$ and $H_2(f)$, use
$H_1(a f - (a-1)(1000\,Hz))$ and $H_2(a f - (a-1)(1000\,Hz))$
for some choice of $a>1$

It should be easy to see which change to the original function causes this using the properties of the inverse Fourier transform.